# VBA Filter before copying and pasting data

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a Macro that looks for open Excel files with a specific file name and then copies data to a specific tab in the worksheet.

The source data has around 489k rows but I only need around roughly 8k of them.

How do i add code that filters the data in the open excel file before pasting?

Thanks!

```
Option Explicit


Sub CopyData()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandle

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim Wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wB As Workbook
    Dim rngToCopy As Range

    For Each wB In Application.Workbooks
        If Left(wB.Name, 21) = "xxx_xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx" Then
            Set Wb1 = wB
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not Wb1 Is Nothing Then '<~~ check if you actually found the needed workbook
        Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook

        With Wb1.Sheets(12)
            Set rngToCopy = .Range("$A:$AM", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        End With
        wb2.Sheets(2).Range("$A:$AM").Resize(rngToCopy.Rows.Count).Value = rngToCopy.Value
    End If
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Action

BeforeExit:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub
'We land here in case of an error
ErrorHandle:
MsgBox Err.Description & " Sub Something"
Resume BeforeExit 'Sends you back to BeforeExit

End Sub
```

Ideally, i would have a filter before copying and pasting the range from wb1 to wb2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code after moving -->   rngToCopy.Value  <--  and after  EndWith

Change the range to be proper, and the Field and Criteria for you filter

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BI$1801").AutoFilter Field:=47, Criteria1:="MoWe"
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I'm a little confused, 

"Add the following code after moving --> rngToCopy.Value <-- "

Are you saying move that code down a line or remove it completely. 

EX:

With Wb1.Sheets(12)
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BI$1801").AutoFilter Field:=47, Criteria1:="MoWe"
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
            Set rngToCopy = .Range("$A:$AM", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        End With
        wb2.Sheets(2).Range("$A:$AM").Resize(rngToCopy.Rows.Count).Value = rngToCopy.Value
    End If
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Comment: Probably -- the filter needs to be applied to the source (which I believe is WB1).  The "ActiveSheet" may need to be replaced with "Wb1.Sheets(12)".  What do you get when you try it?  and try a variation?  Where is the PASTE statement that actually copies the data?